# Lock scrollview at specific point with bounce back effect

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, scrollview

Is there any way to lock scrollview programatically at specific place with having native 
apple bounce back effect?

I have infinite scrollview and would like to lock at some specific place. I found out that 
I can use `scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset` to figure out that the locking point
is going to be crossed and intervene like this:

`[self setContentOffset:CGPointMake(LockPositionX, LockPositionY) animated:YES];`

However this doesn't have native bounce back and rubber banding effect. I try to workaround it with
modifying scrollview.decelerationRate but it looks like it cannot have values other than
UIScrollViewDecelerationRateNormal or UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast.

Maybe I'm missing something and there is some hidden way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the easiest way is to actually use native bounce back implementation. 
Event though our scrollView `contentSize` have e.g. vertical bounds from 0 to 1000 if we put some all the previous with negative origin (out of screen) its going to be visible (rendered) when we bounce back.

If then for some reason we want to move the locking point the previous elements we just have to shift all the elements down so that only elements above the locking points have negative origin

Answer (score 0):

add below code in `scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset`

---

```
if(lockingpointreached)
{
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f delay:0.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^ {
    [self setContentOffset:CGPointMake(LockPositionX-20, LockPositionY-20)];
} completion:NULL];
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: this looks like some way of workaround. The problem here is that no matter how fast we flint and what current speed of scroller (fast or slow) is we always animate for the same duration 0.3 and jump to the same statically shifted position (-20).  We can try to simulate those parameters with some function that takes current scroller speed but I found its hard to make it work really smooth.